# Can I get the simulator to rotate in slow motion?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Does anyone know if I can get the simulator to rotate in slow motion, so that I can analyze what's really going on with my weird looking rotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, enable simulate hardware keyboard and press shift three times (fast).

Answer (score 3):

In the simulator from recent XCodes there is a menu Debug -> Toggle slow animations